# using the 'not' operator in Eclipse Prolog

Tags: prolog, operators

I have a rule to calculate distance between two points in which I say

```
distance(X1,Y1,X2,Y2,D) :- at(Car1,X1,Y1), at(Car2,X2,Y2), not(X1=X2),not(Y1=Y2), D is sqrt((X2 - X1)*(X2 - X1) + (Y2 - Y1)*(Y2 - Y1)).
```

And this works fine. The not operation works exactly as intended. But later on I have this rule.

```
canTurnLeft(Car,X,Y) :- at(Car,X,Y), light(green,X,Y), not(distance(X,Y,A,B,D), D < 80, oppDir(X,Y,A,B)).
```

And it spits out "calling an undefined procedure not(....)"

Can you not use the not operator over multiple and's? If not, how can I return false if there is ANY car travelling in the opposite direction within 80 units?

New to Prolog so any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `not/1` is deprecated. Use the standard `\+/1` operator/built-in control construct instead. Same advice given by @hakank applies.

Comment: @hakank: Please remove implementation specific tags when the question effectively applies to any Prolog. Here by using `(\+)/1` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`not/1` takes one argument. But in your second case there are 3 arguments. Try to enclose the three parameters in parenthesis:

```
canTurnLeft(Car,X,Y) :- 
        at(Car,X,Y), 
        light(green,X,Y), 
        not((distance(X,Y,A,B,D), D < 80, oppDir(X,Y,A,B))).
```

A simpler example:

```
X = 3, not((X = 2, X = 4)).
```